# How can i join two application packages into one?

Tags: android-intent

Some help needed please..I have created an application package                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 which needs to invoke an mp3 player, which is in another application package. How can I connect those together?

Answer (score 0):

When you call another package class then import (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) then auto import package in your current package class.